# Completely Stumped, HTTP Client Android

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am making an Android application and I have run into a bit of a stump.

What I am doing is trying to get the info from a PHP file on a remote server that is hooked to a DB. However I get Exception: null in the Logcat, My code:

```
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        System.out.println("1");
        httppost= new HttpPost("MYSITE/MYPHP.PHP");
        System.out.println("1");
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        System.out.println("1");
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid",userConfig.uid));
        System.out.println("1");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        System.out.println("1");
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println("1");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        System.out.println("1");
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response: " + response);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Response: " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The 'System.out.println("1");' is for debugging.

My logcat output

```
10-10 22:53:44.382  24228-24228/PACKAGENAME  I/System.out﹕ 1
10-10 22:53:44.382  24228-24228/PACKAGENAME  I/System.out﹕ 1
10-10 22:53:44.382  24228-24228/PACKAGENAME  I/System.out﹕ 1
10-10 22:53:44.382  24228-24228/PACKAGENAME  I/System.out﹕ 1
10-10 22:53:44.383  24228-24228/PACKAGENAME  I/System.out﹕ 1
10-10 22:53:44.407  24228-24228/PACKAGENAME  I/System.out﹕ Exception: null
```

So as you can see it gets this line

```
response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I have no clue what is going on, yes I do have the proper permissions!

Comment: add the line `e.printStackTrace();` to your catch block...stack trace may give us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this from the main thread?

Android does not allow you to execute long running operations (like network operations such as HTTP requests) on the main thread. [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)

Comment: Thanks, it was the main thread, it should have crashed I thought, totally overlooked it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be related to multipart entity, see the below code . Its tested. Tune it to your needs.

```
public static String post(String url, String imagePath, String apikey) {
String response = null;
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    entity.addPart("xyz", new FileBody(new File(imagePath)));
    entity.addPart("abc", new StringBody(apikey,
            ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
    httpPost.setEntity(entity.build());

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return response;
```

}